# jquery 1.4.4 class selectors slowness in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

just upgraded from jquery 1.4.2 to 1.4.4 and i've encountered a performance problem which i think has something to do with a lot of class selectors,
sometimes even explorer crashes and in 1.4.2 its working perfect..

Comment: Funny, I just upgraded mine recently an my IE started crashing too.  I didn't make the connection.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the latest version (1.5), which fixes 83 bugs since the last version?

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question...

Comment: the question is if anybody knows the reason jquery 1.4.4 performance issue ?

Comment: jquery 1.5 is now available, have you tested against it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter has had performance issues with 1.4.4 and went back to 1.4.2 until the jQuery team fixes it.  The creator of jQuery talks about it a little bit here in terms of the selector engine:

http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/